# Вывод переменных из таблицы Lua

Tags: lua

Я создал и заполнил table в Lua строками с двумя переменными.

Как сделать отдельный вывод 1-й и 2-й переменной из строки таблицы?

Вот мой пример:

```
-- https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-lua-online/
-- https://replit.com/languages/lua

tbl=tbl or {}
table.insert(tbl, "{ЯНАО}{Ямало-ненецкий автономный округ}")
table.insert(tbl, "{ОГКМ}{Оренбургское газоконденсатное месторождение}")
table.insert(tbl, "{LED}{Light emitting diode}")
table.insert(tbl, "{FET}{Field effect transistor}")
table.insert(tbl, "{ЛПР}{Лицо, принимающее решения}")
table.insert(tbl, "{БД}{База данных}")
table.insert(tbl, "{P2P}{Peer-to-Peer}")
table.insert(tbl, "{XML}{extensible markup language}")
table.insert(tbl, "{ОГКМ}{Оренбургское газоконденсатное месторождение}")
table.insert(tbl, "{HTTP}{Hypertext Transfer Protocol}")
table.insert(tbl, "{SCADA}{Supervisory control and data acquisition}")
table.insert(tbl, "{ОООООООООДА}{Очень Очень Очень Очень Очень Очень Очень Очень Очень Длинная Аббревиатура}")


for i,n in ipairs(tbl) do
    print(i, n)
end

print("-----------")

print("Отдельный вывод 1-й и 2-й переменной строки таблицы (Как вывести????):")

print(tbl[1])

print("-----------")

table.sort(tbl)

print("-----------")

for i,n in ipairs(tbl) do
    print(i, n)
end

print("-----------")
```

Comment: для чего такой странный вид строк? или такие входные данные, можно ведь просто вставлять значения в таблицу с именованными индексами?

Comment: @Mike V. Я только начал разбираться с Lua. Использую его в LuaLaTeX. Такой вариант был в примере, который я использовал. 
Есть еще такие варианты:
table.insert(tbl, {abbr="ЯНАО", desc="Ямало-ненецкий автономный округ"})
tbl["ЯНАО"] = "Ямало-ненецкий автономный округ"
Я не знаю как лучше.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

используйте паттерн для разделения строки на 2 части, например такой:

```
local tbl=tbl or {}
table.insert(tbl, "{ЯНАО}{Ямало-ненецкий автономный округ}")
table.insert(tbl, "{ОГКМ}{Оренбургское газоконденсатное месторождение}")
table.insert(tbl, "{LED}{Light emitting diode}")
table.insert(tbl, "{FET}{Field effect transistor}")
table.insert(tbl, "{ЛПР}{Лицо, принимающее решения}")
table.insert(tbl, "{БД}{База данных}")
table.insert(tbl, "{P2P}{Peer-to-Peer}")
table.insert(tbl, "{XML}{extensible markup language}")
table.insert(tbl, "{ОГКМ}{Оренбургское газоконденсатное месторождение}")
table.insert(tbl, "{HTTP}{Hypertext Transfer Protocol}")
table.insert(tbl, "{SCADA}{Supervisory control and data acquisition}")
table.insert(tbl, "{ОООООООООДА}{Очень Очень Очень Очень Очень Очень Очень Очень Очень Длинная Аббревиатура}")
table.sort(tbl)
print("-----------")
for i,n in ipairs(tbl) do
    local k , v =  n:match("{(.-)}{(.-)}")
    print(i, k,v)
end
print("-----------")
```

напечатает:

```
   1    FET    Field effect transistor
    2    HTTP    Hypertext Transfer Protocol
    3    LED    Light emitting diode
    4    P2P    Peer-to-Peer
    5    SCADA    Supervisory control and data acquisition
    6    XML    extensible markup language
    7    БД    База данных
    8    ЛПР    Лицо, принимающее решения
    9    ОГКМ    Оренбургское газоконденсатное месторождение
    10    ОГКМ    Оренбургское газоконденсатное месторождение
    11    ОООООООООДА    Очень Очень Очень Очень Очень Очень Очень Очень Очень Длинная Аббревиатура
    12    ЯНАО    Ямало-ненецкий автономный округ
```